# Recursive SQL query on a tree with stop condition to stop digging in the sub tree

Tags: mysql

I am using an "Accounts" tree structure in a table.

in this example data is:

```
 +---- +-----------+------+-----------------+
| id  | parent_id | data | stop_descending |
+---- +-----------+------+-----------------+
|  1  |      NULL |    x |               0 |
|  2  |         1 |    y |               0 |
|  3  |         1 |    z |               1 |
|  4  |         3 |    g |               0 |
|  5  |         3 |    l |               0 |
|  6  |         2 |    x |               0 |
|  7  |         2 |    u |               1 |
|  8  |         1 |    y |               1 |
|  9  |         7 |    y |               0 |
|  10 |         9 |    a |               0 |
+----+-----------+------+-------+-----------
```

I need to get all leaves in this tree but stop digging in the sub-tree when the stop_digging is true.

In this sample, I need to get this expected Result

```
+----+-----------+------+-----------------+
| id | parent_id | data | stop_digging    |
+----+-----------+------+-----------------+
|  1 |      NULL |    x |               0 |
|  2 |         1 |    y |               0 |
|  3 |         1 |    z |               1 |
|  6 |         2 |    x |               0 |
|  7 |         2 |    u |               1 |
|  8 |         1 |    y |               1 |
+----+-----------+------+-------+----------
```

the nodes that will be removed are:

```
+---- +-----------+------+-----------------+
| id  | parent_id | data | stop_digging    |
+---- +-----------+------+-----------------+
|  4  |         3 |    g |               0 |
|  5  |         3 |    l |               0 |
|  9  |         7 |    y |               0 |
|  10 |         9 |    a |               0 |
+----+-----------+------+-------+-----------
```

```
CREATE TABLE Accounts (
    id int,
    parent_id int ,
    data  varchar(10),
    stop_digging int
);

INSERT INTO Accounts
    (`id`, `parent_id`, `data`, `stop_digging`)
VALUES
    (1, null,'x',0),
    (2,1,'y',0),
    (3,1,'z',1),
    (4,3,'g',0),
    (5,3,'l',0),
    (6,2,'x',0),
    (7,2,'u',1),
    (8,1,'y',1),
    (9,7,'y',0),
    (10,9,'a',0)
;
```

I can get all the nodes but I don't know a way jut to take just the data I need as I described earlier

```sql
select  id,
        data,
        parent_id, stop_digging
from    (select * from Accounts
         order by parent_id, id) Accounts,
        (select @pv := '1') initialisation
where   find_in_set(parent_id, @pv) > 0
and     @pv := concat(@pv, ',', id);
```

Comment: Please explain how expected Result is generated and when nodes need to be removed.

Comment: I wish I knew:-),
I think that I need a condition, stop searching in the subtree when stop_digging is "true". and I don know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

I believe you requested answer is wrong. 10 must be included because 9 has a 0 in stop_digging column.

So because of This

```
SELECT a1.* FROM Accounts a1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Accounts UNION SELECT NULL,0, 0, 0) a2 
ON a1.parent_id = a2.id OR (a1.parent_id IS NULL AND a2.id IS NULL) 
WHERE a2.stop_digging = 0;
```

Gives you following response

```
id  parent_id   data    stop_digging
1               x       0
2   1           y       0
3   1           z       1
6   2           x       0
7   2           u       1
8   1           y       1
10  9           a       0
```

The

> UNION SELECT NULL,0, 0, 0

And

> or (a1.parent_id IS NULL AND a2.id IS NULL)

Parts are needed because the first row don't match because it didn't end up in a row with stop_digging = 0.

See dbfiddle Example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=46c7164f4b3b14e5e722ffcd822e8762

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer . but 10 cant be included since 10 is "under" 9 and 9is "under " 7 and 7 has stop_digging =1. so if 7 is a stop condition we cant get 9 and 10

Comment: That are two. Mysql can't make recursive the fas, at least when it doesn't know. If there are two level  you can  built like the first that i constructed, but if you can have a true recursive tree to search with different layern, you need a stored procudure